# Shiny server: Fatal error: unable to open the base package

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I just installed shiny server and I get an error when I load the shiny web page:

An error has occurred. The application failed to start shows on the right side of the screen.

Then I checked the log and shows:

su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Fatal error: unable to open the base package

When I type su - shiny and I try to run R I also get the Fatal error: unable to open the base package, so I guess there is a problem with R.

I can load R when I'm root or R user and apparently R works fine.

Any idea? Could it be a PATH problem? If yes, I couldn't find it out.

Thanks in advance.